# Django form wizard multiple formsets on one page

Tags: python, django, forms, django-formwizard

I am trying to create a form in Django with the form wizard where there are multiple (repeating) formsets in the same step of the wizard.

What I have is:

```
# forms.py
class FormStep1A(forms.Form):
    answerA = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    remarkA = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

class FormStep1B(forms.Form):
    answerB = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    remarkB = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

class FormStep1(forms.Form):
    partA = formset_factory(FormStep1A)
    partB = formset_factory(FormStep1B)
```

and

```
# urls.py
STEPS = (
    ('1', FormStep1),
    # ...
)
# FormWizard is a subclass of NamedUrlSessionWizardView
wizard = FormWizard.as_view(STEPS, url_name='form_new_step')
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^new/(?P<step>.+)/$', wizard,
        name='form_new_step'),
    url(r'^new/$', wizard, name='form_new'),
)
```

And my template looks the same as in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#creating-templates-for-the-forms). However, my form is rendered empty with no fields at all.

I know there are similar questions or recipes out there:

- [Django formwizard with formsets and forms on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065743/django-formwizard-with-formsets-and-forms-on-same-page)
- [django wizard, using form and formset in the same step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644357/django-wizard-using-form-and-formset-in-the-same-step)
- [Combining a Form and a FormSet in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090043/combining-a-form-and-a-formset-in-django): How to pass them in the context?

But I just cannot get this to work. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

**UPDATE:** My template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
  {{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <h3>{% trans "Questionnaire" %}</h3>
      <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ wizard.management_form }}
          {% if wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
            {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
              {{ form }}
            {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            {{ wizard.form }}
          {% endif %}
          {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
            <button class="button tiny" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "First step" %}</button>
            <button class="button tiny" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "Prev step" %}</button>
          {% endif %}
          <input class="button tiny" type="submit" value="{% trans "Submit" %}"/>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you add your template?

Comment: Is your `FormWizard` view a subclass of `SessionWizardView`?

Comment: `FormWizard` is a subclass of `NamedUrlSessionWizardView`